# PHP max_execution_time impact on performance

Tags: php, apache

I have a VM with apache and php 7.3.
The VM have multiple wep apps.
Because there is a process in an app that need about 30 minutes to finish, if I set max_execution_time to 30 minutes, will it affect other web apps in the VM too?
Like other apps will become slow or "blocked" while the 30 minute process still processing?

Comment: It will depend on the power of the RAM of your VM and the processing of the task which lasts 30 min. But if you have others running at that time if you don't have enough RAM it can slow down your VM.

Comment: Long running processes should be done via a Cronjob (CLI does not have a time limitation by default)

Comment: Don't use a global solution to a local problem. The app itself can allocate as much time as it wants.

Comment: @Patrick62 so it will be ok if I add more RAM to the VM?

LarsStegelitz, unfortunatelly this process need to be done by the user...

ÁlvaroGonzález, do you mean instead of using set max_execution_time, I should just use ini_set(max_execution_time,30minute)?
I can do that, but the question still same, will other web apps's performance got affected/blocked by this 30 minute process?

Comment: If you change the system-wide value, all scripts that use the default value will see their maximum allowed time changed. Performance-wise, you introduce the chance that a script gone wild (e.g., an infinite loop due to a bug) consumes CPU cycles until the application server is restarted, what means less CPU for other legit tasks.